# How To Get Href Link Using Xpath C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

`<a href="/buffet-lau--nuong-hon-200-mon-an-huong-vi-han-quoc-tai-seoul-garden-hien-dai-nhat-vn-170ecccd214b42f8/dat-mua" id="cmPurchaseLink" name="cmPurchaseLink"></a>`

how to get

`"/buffet-lau--nuong-hon-200-mon-an-huong-vi-han-quoc-tai-seoul-garden-hien-dai-nhat-vn-170ecccd214b42f8/dat-mua" id="cmPurchaseLink" name="cmPurchaseLink"`

using xpath (C#)?

Comment: Please post the xml structure that you have. Need to use SelectSingleNode to get the value of any node ( comment of @user709634 )

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the XML markup you posted resides in an [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx), you can write:

```
string href
    = yourXmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//a[@id='cmPurchaseLink']/@href").Value;
```

Comment: IntelliSense does not show "Value" as an option.  Maybe things have changed in 4 years?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), and i would use this  :

```
string summary = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@id='cmPurchaseLink']")[0].Attributes["href"].Value
```